# How should exercise 1-5.7(B) from Stoll be read?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation

I asked a question about this exercise in the past ([Is there a standard way to represent a general set theoretical equation in one variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2584788/342834)), and don't mean to "re-ask".  But I'm unclear as to how I should read the phrase *"only complements of individual sets,"* in Stoll's outline of a proof.

Specifically, does it mean that both an individual set *and* its complement may appear; or does it mean that only the complements of the given constant sets should appear? I believe it means the former, but the wording is a bit nebulous (to me).

This is exercise 1-5.7(B) from Stoll, Robert R.. Set Theory and Logic (Dover Books on Mathematics) (Kindle Location 787). Dover Publications. Kindle Edition.

> Prove that an equation in $\mathcal{X}$ with righthand member $\emptyset$ can be reduced to one of the form $\left(\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{X}\right)\cup\left(\mathcal{B}\cap\mathcal{\overline{X}}\right)=\emptyset$. (Suggestion: Sketch a proof along these lines. First, apply the DeMorgan laws until only complements of individual sets appear. Then expand the resulting lefthand side by the distributive law 3 so as to transform it into the union of several terms $\mathcal{T}_{i}$, each of which is an intersection of several individual sets. Next, if in any $\mathcal{T}_{i}$ neither $\mathcal{X}$ nor $\mathcal{\overline{X}}$ appears, replace $\mathcal{T}_{i}$ by $\mathcal{T}_{i}\cap\left(\mathcal{X}\cup\mathcal{\overline{X}}\right)$ and expand. Finally, group together the terms containing $\mathcal{X}$ and those containing $\mathcal{\overline{X}}$ and apply the distributive law 3.)

**I'm not asking for a solution.**

My intuitive understanding is that, for any solution $\mathcal{X},$ we can exclusively group the $\mathcal{T}_{i}$ into those which are disjoint with $\mathcal{X},$ and those which are subsets of $\mathcal{X}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the complement operation should only appear when applied to individual sets, rather than to more complicated expressions.  So for instance, you should never have an expression like $\overline{A\cup B}$ or $\overline{A\cap (\overline{B}\cup C)}$, where you are taking the complement of a compound expression.  It would perhaps be more precise to use the phrasing "complements of only individual sets": the "only" is restricting what you can take complements of.

Comment: Perhaps "... until only complements of individual sets appear" could be stated as *... until any complements which appear are those of individual sets.*  Would that amount to the same thing?